# request java location permissions

Tags: java, android

when I execute this code

```
        while (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
```

I get this warning
W/Activity: Can request only one set of permissions at a time
W/Activity: Can request only one set of permissions at a time
is there any way to fix this?

Comment: you are sending an array of Strings, have you tried adding both you want to check in said array?

Answer (score -1):

Two things here, firstly I don't think you need two set of Location Permissions, if you are using `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` then Coarse should be covered well under it.

Secondly, instead of sending separate request for permissions, you should make one combined set of requests and send it. That should work.

```
int permissions_code = 42; 
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};

 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, permissions_code);
```